# Android programatically setting a ListView row to activated

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm using the following selector to change set a row's background when it is selected

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/row_sel" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/row_neut"/>
```

It works fine when a row is phyiscally clicked. All I want to do is programatically set a row to be selected. I thought this would be trivial, but after over an hour of trying and googling, I can't find an answer.

Things I've tried:

- `listView.setSelection(0)`
- `listView.setItemChecked(0)`
- `listView.getItem(0).setActivated(true) //fails: getChildCount() is 0`
- `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, `listView.invalidate() //out of desperation`

I could obviously use a hack within the adapter (i.e assign selected/neutral Drawable each time) but I'd rather have it clean.

Comment: That's really what the `android:state_selected` state is for. Can't you simply add that to the drawable definition? After that, `listView.setSelection(0)` should give you exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

listView.performItemClick(listView, position, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));

Answer (score -1):

USer `listView.setSelection(0);`

and if you want a background color for a listview selected, you could use Transition

Comment: selection: tried, read question. transition: definitely not relevant here.

Comment: "All I want to do is programatically set a row to be selected".,.Well setSelection works for me. Thanks for the downvote.